# Foi tão ruim assim essa sugestão de tag?

Tags: debate, edições-sugeridas

Fiz uma [sugestão no fragmento na tag](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/113567) [dry](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dry) hoje e ela foi rejeitada com a seguinte explicação:

> Esta edição não faz a publicação mais fácil de ser lida, mais fácil de ser encontrada, mais precisa ou mais acessível. As mudanças são completamente supérfluas ou de fato prejudicam a legibilidade.

E eu gostaria de saber, se ela realmente foi tão ruim assim, que talvez tenha chegado ao ponto de prejudicar a legibilidade. Além, disso o que mais me intrigou foi que **nem existia** um fragmento de tag.

Enviei esta sugestão para ser analisada:

> Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) é uma filosofia de desenvolvimento de software que visa reduzir redundância e repetição de código. Parte do princípio fundamental que nunca se deve repetir algo que já está criado, e sim definir um método, ou propriedade em um só lugar e reaproveitá-lo em qualquer outro.

Essa resposta eu formulei com base em umas pergunta respondida aqui no SO<sup>pt</sup>([1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23052/o-que-s%C3%A3o-os-princ%C3%ADpios-dry-kiss-e-yagni),[2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/120931/o-dry-%C3%A9-para-evitar-redund%C3%A2ncias-certo)) e a própria tag do SO<sup>en</sup>([1](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dry/info)).

Não que eu esteja dizendo que porque olhou no SO<sup>en</sup> vai ser aprovada direto, mas realmente eu gostaria de saber onde tem problemas, nessa sugestão:

- Eu não demonstrei esforço?
- Prejudiquei a legibilidade?
- Utilizei conceitos incorretos na tag?
- Foram supérfulas as mudanças?

A outra sugestão da tag [stackexchange](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackexchange), eu até entendi, o @bigown e o @diegofm falaram que não fazia muito sentido ter no site principal e sim no Meta, mas essa sugestão também foi ruim?

Comment: Eu aceitaria, acho que para o fragmento da tag está bem simples de entender. Explicações mais detalhadas e técnicas poderiam utilizar a wiki da tag (que até então não existe).

Comment: Eu acho que é porque "**Resumos devem descrever por que e quando a tag deve ser utilizada**".

Comment: Sou de acordo com a rejeição, mas não com o motivo escolhido.

Comment: Ok, isso é uma melhor explicação do que "esta edição não faz..."

Comment: Era pra realmente ver se eu estava tão ruim assim nas sugestões de edição

Comment: Eu aceitaria a edição que você sugeriu. P.s.: não sou o mesmo @Renan que já disse isso no primeiro comentário.

Comment: @Renan é sim...

Comment: Se calhar o problema é que  a tag [tag:dry] nao devia sequer existir.